# Report Portal requires a webdriver?

Tags: reportportal

Im currently doing api automation and noticed that when i integrate report portal that it requires a webdriver. This maybe due to taking a screenshot but is there a way to disable that dependency?

Answer (score 1):

ReportPortal does not require WebDriver, because it interacts with testing engine/framework (junit, testNG, cucumber, etc) only. If there is a transitive dependency that comes from ReportPortal's libs, than please, mention the agent you're using explicitly - it will be considered as a bug